# Youtube toggle related section - Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube, tampermonkey, togglebutton

I have modified an existing script to create a button for hide/show the related sidebar on youtube. The related section supposed to be hidden by default. Similarly like the FF add-on YT Clean.

The button works well if the 'related' block is visible by default (no  `button.click()` in the code).
Also works if I reload the ...watch page.

But if I am coming from the default youtube page or search results (click on a video to watch), I have to click on the button twice to hide the 'related' block.

I am really a beginner (I did not write this), so appreciate any help.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Youtube - toggle related
// @namespace       -
// @version         1.0
// @match           https://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant           none
// @require         https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// @run-at          document-end
// @noframes
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
  'use strict';
  console.log('X');
  let target = document.querySelectorAll('body')[0];
  let options = {'childList': true, 'subtree' : true};

  function callback(observer, node){
    if (node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == '#secondary-inner'){
      $('#secondary-inner').hide(); 
    }
  }

  let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
      if (mutation.type === 'childList'){
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(node){
          callback(observer, node);
        });
      }
    });
  });

  let button = document.createElement('button');
      button.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g fill="currentColor"><path d="M4 14h4v-4H4v4zm0 5h4v-4H4v4zM4 9h4V5H4v4zm5 5h12v-4H9v4zm0 5h12v-4H9v4zM9 5v4h12V5H9z"/></g></svg>';
      button.style = `
                      background: transparent;
                      border: 0;
                      color: rgb(96,96,96);
                      cursor: pointer;
                      outline: 0;
      `;
  
  let hide = false;

    button.onclick = ()=>{
    hide = !hide;
    if (hide){
      if ($('#secondary-inner')[0]) 
        $('#secondary-inner').hide()
      else
        observer.observe(target, options);
      
      console.log(`hide`);
    }
    else{
      observer.disconnect();
      console.log(`show`);

      $('#secondary-inner').show();
    }
  }

  button.click();
  
  let menu = $('#end')[0];
      menu.insertBefore(button, menu.lastElementChild);

  console.log('inserted');

} )()
```

Comment: Your code seems to work well for me, even when coming from a search or the main page. Can you provide the specific steps you're taking to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Really? For me it keeps producing the same result when I start from the main yt page or search results and click on any videos to watch. The related section is not hidden until I click the icon twice. As soon as I am on the the 'watch' page and and click on the icon twice or reload, it works well even I go back to the main page. I tried with both tampermonkey and violentmankey and using a clean FF profile (for sure not to be disturbed by any add-on). I am on FF 78.11.0esr but tried on FF 88.0.1 either. Also some rare cases the script is not loaded at all, I need to reload the page. @ev-haus

Comment: I guess the problem is the the button.click() . Is there any other method to make the related block hidden by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the element hidden all the time by default without any buttons, you can do:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Youtube - Hide Related Sidebar
// @namespace       -
// @version         1.0
// @match           https://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant           none
// @require         https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
// @run-at          document-end
// @noframes
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
    'use strict';

    const callback = () => $('#secondary-inner').hide();

    const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
            if (mutation.type === 'childList'){
                mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(node){
                    callback();
                });
            }
        });
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, {'childList': true, 'subtree' : true});
})(
```

)

Comment: Thanks man! I inserted your code into mine, some other modifications and it works just fine with button. Exactly what I wanted. Gonna test it for a couple of days and will post on greasyfork.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version. Any comments/revision are welcome.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Youtube - Toggle Related Sidebar
// @namespace       -
// @version         1.2
// @match           https://www.youtube.com/*
// @include         https://www.youtube.com/watch*
// @grant           none
// @require         https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
// @run-at          document-end
// @noframes
// ==/UserScript==
    
(function(){
  'use strict';
  
  let target = document.querySelectorAll('body')[0];
  let options = {'childList': true, 'subtree' : true};
  
  const callback = () => $('#related').hide();
  
      const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
            if (mutation.type === 'childList'){
                mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(node){
                    callback();
                });
            }
        });
    });

  observer.observe(document.body, {'childList': true, 'subtree' : true});

  let button = document.createElement('button');
      button.innerHTML = '<svg width="48" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g fill="currentColor"><path d="M4 14h4v-4H4v4zm0 5h4v-4H4v4zM4 9h4V5H4v4zm5 5h12v-4H9v4zm0 5h12v-4H9v4zM9 5v4h12V5H9z"/></g></svg>';
      button.style = ` background: transparent; border: 0; color: rgb(96,96,96); outline: 0; `;
  
  let hide = true;

    button.onclick = ()=>{
    hide = !hide;
    if (hide){
      if ($('#related')[0]) 
        $('#related').hide()
      else
        observer.observe(target, options);
        console.log(`hide`);
    }
    else{
      observer.disconnect();
      console.log(`show`);

      $('#related').show();
    }
  }

  
  let menu = $('#end')[0];
      menu.insertBefore(button, menu.lastElementChild);

  console.log('inserted');

} )()
```